# Fluentd Matching tags

Tags: logging, kubernetes, fluentd

I'm trying to figure out how can a rename a field (or create a new field with the same value ) with Fluentd

Like:

```
agent: Chrome ....
```

To:

```
agent: Chrome
user-agent: Chrome
```

but for a specific type of logs, like `**nginx**`.

I'm trying to user `record_reformer` but it doesn't apply for a second filter:

```
<filter kubernetes.**.nginx-ingress-controller-**.log>
  @type parser
  format /^(?<host>[^ ]*) (?<domain>[^ ]*) \[(?<x_forwarded_for>[^\]]*)\] (?<server_port>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+[^\"])(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")? (?<request_length>[^ ]*) (?<request_time>[^ ]*) (?:\[(?<proxy_upstream_name>[^\]]*)\] )?(?<addr>[^ ]*) (?<response_length>[^ ]*) (?<response_time>[^ ]*) (?<status>[^ ]*)$/
  time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
  key_name log
  types server_port:integer,code:integer,size:integer,request_length:integer,request_time:float,upstream_response_length:integer,upstream_response_time:float,upstream_status:integer
  reserve_data true
</filter>

<filter kubernetes.**>
    @type kubernetes_metadata
</filter>

<filter kubernetes.**>
 @type grep
 <regexp>
     key $.kubernetes.labels.fluentd
     pattern true
 </regexp>
</filter>

<filter kubernetes.**.deployment-name**>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    level ${record["Level"]}
  </record>
</filter>

<match kubernetes.**>
  @type elasticsearch
  include_tag_key true
  host "#{ENV['OUTPUT_HOST']}"
  port "#{ENV['OUTPUT_PORT']}"
  scheme "#{ENV['OUTPUT_SCHEME']}"
  reload_connections true
  logstash_format true
</match>

<match kubernetes.**>
  @type record_reformer
  remove_keys log,kubernetes
  tag mytag.generic
  <record>
    name ${record['kubernetes']['labels']['app']}
    namespace ${record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']}
  </record>
</match>

<match kubernetes.**api**>
  @type record_reformer
  remove_keys log,kubernetes
  tag mytag.api
  <record>
    user_agent ${record['req']['headers']['user-agent']}
  </record>
</match>
```

In such a case it doesn't send the logs for the `mytag.generic`

Comment: Any reason you are using `record_reformer` over `record_transformer`?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar use case, and like @embik said, using record_transformer seems like a more fit choice. In my case I'm trying to downcase a key in a json record fluentd is going through, here's the conf -

```
<filter kubernetes.**.deployment-name**>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    level ${record["Level"]}
  </record>
</filter>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actually, I tried bt was basically not working. I was getting:
`unknown placeholder ${record["Level"]} found` and the field is there. I updated my question with more info.

Comment: Please add your `source` configuration. perhaps something needs fixing there.

Comment: Another useful tip - try running fluentd once with a `@type stdout` that matches all records right after your source, and add one of the records to the question. This will greatly help troubleshooting the problem.